# Can not pass arguments to http.addFilterBefore()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Here is code

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig{
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

When i try to do this
`http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`
I got this
[image]

Here is my AuthTokenFilter code

```java
@Slf4j
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {

                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFormJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, when i try to startup application, i got this error

java: cannot access javax.servlet.Filter
class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TaskManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TaskManager</name>
    <description>TaskManager</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I saw somewhere here that this denendency migh help

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But this did not help me

Comment: First you can remove all the spring version numbers in your pom. You have defined the spring parent, so the parent will automatically select spring versions for you that are compatible with each other. Also you dont need jjwt, spring boot already comes included with Nimbus which is a jwt library. So you can remove that dependency also. Im guessing you have followed a bad blogpost, written by someone that doesnt understand spring

Comment: Yeah, removing the spring version numbers actually helped, thank you